# Hyperlink will not show Display proper text

Tags: python, ms-office, pywin32

I am trying to add a hyperlink to a cell to open a folder the code below makes the hyperlink in the proper cell and is when clicked redirects to the proper folder but it does not display the text provided it instead displays the folder name e.g. (:C:\Documents and Settings\abulle\Desktop\Python-Stuff\Spec-Load\Formatted\) instead of 'Folder'

```
sheet.Hyperlinks.Add( Anchor = sheet.Cells(7,21), Address = "C:\\Python-Stuff\\Spec-Load\\Formatted\\" , TextToDisplay = "Folder")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a stopgap answer, a kludge. I don't have time at the moment to find a better answer. If this was part of my day job I'd spend the time to find out what's going on.

I've had the same issue (Excel shows the link address as the cell text instead of the `TextToDisplay` value supplied on `Hyperlinks.Add()`)

My code works under unit test when invoked by running the Python 2.7 interpreter - the value of the `'TextToDisplay'` argument is displayed in the cell. The 'production' code (built using `py2exe`) displays the hyperlink. I'll find out why some day (this is low background work.)

`Hyperlinks.Add` returns the `Hyperlink` object it just added. The workaround is to examine the `TextToDisplay` property of that object - if it's not what I want, I assign the correct value to  it.

```
link = sheet.Hyperlinks.Add( Anchor = sheet.Cells(7,21),
                             Address = u"C:\\Python-Stuff\\Spec-Load\\Formatted\\" ,
                             TextToDisplay = u"Folder")
if link.TextToDisplay != u"Folder":
    link.TextToDisplay = u"Folder" # kludge
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 def addHyperlink(self, uri_1, summa_, sheetId, rowIndex, colIndex):
    requests = []
    requests.append({
        "updateCells": {
            "rows": [{
                "values": [{
                    'userEnteredValue': {'numberValue': floatG(summa_)},  #
                    'effectiveValue': {'numberValue': floatG(summa_)},
                    'formattedValue': "р." + summa_,
                    'userEnteredFormat': {
                        'numberFormat': {'type': 'NUMBER', 'pattern': '[$р.-419]#,##0.00'},
                        'backgroundColor': {'red': 1, 'green': 1, 'blue': 0.6}, 'borders': {
                            'top': {
                                'style': 'SOLID', 'width': 1, 'color': {}, 'colorStyle': {'rgbColor': {}}},
                            'bottom': {
                                'style': 'SOLID', 'width': 1, 'color': {}, 'colorStyle': {'rgbColor': {}}},
                            'left': {
                                'style': 'SOLID', 'width': 1, 'color': {}, 'colorStyle': {'rgbColor': {}}},
                            'right': {
                                'style': 'SOLID', 'width': 1, 'color': {}, 'colorStyle': {'rgbColor': {}}}},
                        'horizontalAlignment': 'RIGHT', 'verticalAlignment': 'BOTTOM',
                        'textFormat': {
                            'foregroundColor': {'red': 0.06666667, 'green': 0.33333334, 'blue': 0.8},
                            'fontFamily': 'Arial', 'underline': True,
                            'foregroundColorStyle': {
                                'rgbColor': {'red': 0.06666667, 'green': 0.33333334, 'blue': 0.8}},
                            'link': {'uri': uri_1}
                        },
                        'hyperlinkDisplayType': 'LINKED',
                        'backgroundColorStyle': {'rgbColor': {'red': 1, 'green': 1, 'blue': 0.6}}
                    }
                    , 'hyperlink': uri_1, 'note': 'макс',
                }
                ]
            }], "fields": "userEnteredFormat(numberFormat,backgroundColor,horizontalAlignment,verticalAlignment,textFormat)", "start": {
                "sheetId": sheetId, "rowIndex": rowIndex, "columnIndex": colIndex}}})
    body = {
        "requests": requests}
    request = self.service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=self.spreadsheetId, body=body)
    return request.execute()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).